# Inheritance and Casting error (generic interfaces)

Tags: c#, generics, casting, covariance

How can I restructure my code to get rid of the runtime error happening at the point indicated?

`DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>` needs to be able to cast back to `IDataSeries<IDataPoint>` somehow

I have tried using inheritance of two interfaces, like this:

`public class DataSeries<TDataPoint> : IDataSeries<TDataPoint>, IDataSeries<IDataPoint>` but received compiler error:

> `'DataSeries<TDataPoint>'` cannot implement both
>
> `'IDataSeries<TDataPoint>'` and
>
> `'IDataSeries<IDataPoint>'`
>   because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions

Using covariance doesn't seem to be an option because I can't make the interfaces covariant or contravariant.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

class Program {

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var source = new object();

        // compiles fine, but ...
        // runtime error here - cannot cast
        var ds = (IDataSeries<IDataPoint>)new DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>(source);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IDataPoint {
    int Index { get; set; }
    double Value { get; set; }
    DateTime TimeStampLocal { get; set; }
    IDataPoint Clone();
}

public sealed class SimpleDataPoint : IDataPoint {
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStampLocal { get; set; }
    public IDataPoint Clone() {
        return new SimpleDataPoint {
            Index = Index,
            Value = Value,
            TimeStampLocal = TimeStampLocal,
        };
    }
}

public interface IDataSeries<TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {
    object Source { get; }
    int Count { get; }
    double GetValue(int index);
    DateTime GetTimeStampLocal(int index);
    TDataPoint GetDataPoint(int index);
    TDataPoint GetLastDataPoint();
    void Add(TDataPoint dataPoint);
    IDataSeries<TDataPoint> Branch(object source);
}

public class DataSeries<TDataPoint> : IDataSeries<TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {

    readonly List<TDataPoint> _data = new List<TDataPoint>();

    public object Source {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DataSeries(object source) {
        Source = source;
    }

    public int Count {
        get { return _data.Count; }
    }
    public TDataPoint GetDataPoint(int index) {
        return _data[index];
    }
    public TDataPoint GetLastDataPoint() {
        return _data[_data.Count - 1];
    }
    public DateTime GetTimeStampLocal(int index) {
        return _data[index].TimeStampLocal;
    }
    public double GetValue(int index) {
        return _data[index].Value;
    }
    public void Add(TDataPoint dataPoint) {
        _data.Add(dataPoint);
    }

    public IDataSeries<TDataPoint> Branch(object source) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what you posted is a compile time error, not a cast exception.

Comment: @Yuval, the code compiles. I'm looking for a solution to a runtime casting error. The compile error mentioned was an error preventing one possible solution I had tried.

Comment: Actually, I think there's a code smell, I'm not looking just to fix a run-time error but also to structure my code without the smell :)

Comment: You could create two additional interfaces. One covariant : `IReadOnlyDataSeries<out TDataPoint>` and the other one contravariant on TDataPoint: `IWriteOnlyDataSeries<in TDataPoint>`

Comment: Hi @chomba, yups, I was thinking the same way ... then realised that one class can't inherit from both interfaces because of the conflicting variance. But I don't need write-only ... see my final answer below which actually uses the read-only half of your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `new DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>` **is not** `IDataSeries<IDataPoint>`, because calling `IDataSeries<IDataPoint>.Value = new AnotherDataPoint()` and `IDataPoint value = IDataSeries<IDataPointBase>.Value` can fail. That is, runtime can't guarantee that what you're doing is type-safe, so it throws an exception to tell you that. Runtime can only guarantee *one* of these operations to be safe only if your interface is marked as covariant or contravariant. It's marked as neither, so it isn't type-safe, so it can't be done.

If you intend to bypass type safety, you can create an unsafe proxy:

```
public class DataSeries<TDataPoint> : IDataSeries<TDataPoint>
    where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint
{
    // ...

    public IDataSeries<IDataPoint> GetUnsafeProxy ()
    {
        return new UnsafeProxy(this);
    }

    private class UnsafeProxy : IDataSeries<IDataPoint>
    {
        private readonly DataSeries<TDataPoint> _owner;

        public UnsafeProxy (DataSeries<TDataPoint> owner)
        {
            _owner = owner;
        }

        public object Source
        {
            get { return _owner.Source; }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _owner.Count; }
        }

        public double GetValue (int index)
        {
            return _owner.GetValue(index);
        }

        public DateTime GetTimeStampLocal (int index)
        {
            return _owner.GetTimeStampLocal(index);
        }

        public IDataPoint GetDataPoint (int index)
        {
            return _owner.GetDataPoint(index);
        }

        public IDataPoint GetLastDataPoint ()
        {
            return _owner.GetLastDataPoint();
        }

        public void Add (IDataPoint dataPoint)
        {
            _owner.Add((TDataPoint)dataPoint);
        }

        public IDataSeries<IDataPoint> Branch (object source)
        {
            return (IDataSeries<IDataPoint>)_owner.Branch(source);
        }
    }
```

You can use this proxy like this:

```
IDataSeries<IDataPoint> ds = new DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>(source).GetUnsafeProxy();
```

Note that the last two methods use type casting, so calling them is not safe, they can throw in case of incompatible types. If want to cast `DataSeries` not only to base types, but to other types too, you'll have to add even more type casts to the unsafe proxy and lose even more type safety. The choice is yours.

Comment: Yup, awesome answer @Discord, I'm pasting an answer of my own below as well ... this has been a great thinking exercise!!

Comment: Marking your answer as "the answer" because it provides an exact solution (albeit dangerous to use) to the question posed. However I'd be crazy to use it in my code because it would be just silly to create maintenance traps for future developers. (Code smell)

Comment: My answer below (creating the "readonly" dataseries) is what I'll use in my solution ... in fact, declaring input series as "readonly" is really cool because it makes the code's intention super-clear

Answer (score 2):

So my question got me thinking about code smells, and things like "What am I really trying to achieve?"

Well, here's what I figured out I want to achieve: I want to convert `DataSeries<TDataPoint>` to `IReadOnlyDataSeries<IDataPoint>` only when I am passing it as an input to a class that processes read-only data from a `IReadonlyDataSeries<IDataPoint>` object.

Here's the important change made:

```
// here's the covariant, read-only part of the interface declaration
public interface IReadOnlyDataSeries<out TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {
    object Source { get; }
    int Count { get; }
    double GetValue(int index);
    DateTime GetTimeStampLocal(int index);
    TDataPoint GetDataPoint(int index);
    TDataPoint GetLastDataPoint();
}

// add a few bits to the read-write fully-typed interface, breaking covariance,
// but being able to implicitly cast to the covariant readonly version when needed
public interface IDataSeries<TDataPoint> : IReadOnlyDataSeries<TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {
    void Add(TDataPoint dataPoint);
    IDataSeries<TDataPoint> Branch(object source);
}
```

Here's the full version of the revised code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

class Program {

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var source = new object();

        // implicit conversion works great!!
        // therefore I can achieve the goal of passing the fully-typed read-write dataseries
        // into objects that just want simple read-only data
        var inputSeries = new DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>(source);

        // passing inputSeries into the constructor involves an implicit
        // conversion to IReadOnlyDataSeries<IDataPoint>
        var processor = new DataProcessor(inputSeries);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class DataProcessor {

        IReadOnlyDataSeries<IDataPoint> InputSeries;
        DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint> OutputSeries;

        public DataProcessor(IReadOnlyDataSeries<IDataPoint> inputSeries) {
            InputSeries = inputSeries;
            OutputSeries = new DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>(this);
        }
    }
}

public interface IDataPoint {
    int Index { get; set; }
    double Value { get; set; }
    DateTime TimeStampLocal { get; set; }
    IDataPoint Clone();
}

public sealed class SimpleDataPoint : IDataPoint {
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStampLocal { get; set; }
    public IDataPoint Clone() {
        return new SimpleDataPoint {
            Index = Index,
            Value = Value,
            TimeStampLocal = TimeStampLocal,
        };
    }
}

// here's the covariant, read-only part of the interface declaration
public interface IReadOnlyDataSeries<out TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {
    object Source { get; }
    int Count { get; }
    double GetValue(int index);
    DateTime GetTimeStampLocal(int index);
    TDataPoint GetDataPoint(int index);
    TDataPoint GetLastDataPoint();
}

// add a few bits to the read-write fully-typed interface, breaking covariance,
// but being able to implicitly cast to the covariant readonly version when needed
public interface IDataSeries<TDataPoint> : IReadOnlyDataSeries<TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {
    void Add(TDataPoint dataPoint);
    IDataSeries<TDataPoint> Branch(object source);
}

public class DataSeries<TDataPoint> : IDataSeries<TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint {

    readonly List<TDataPoint> _data = new List<TDataPoint>();

    public object Source {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DataSeries(object source) {
        Source = source;
    }

    public int Count {
        get { return _data.Count; }
    }
    public TDataPoint GetDataPoint(int index) {
        return _data[index];
    }
    public TDataPoint GetLastDataPoint() {
        return _data[_data.Count - 1];
    }
    public DateTime GetTimeStampLocal(int index) {
        return _data[index].TimeStampLocal;
    }
    public double GetValue(int index) {
        return _data[index].Value;
    }
    public void Add(TDataPoint dataPoint) {
        _data.Add(dataPoint);
    }

    public IDataSeries<TDataPoint> Branch(object source) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This minimal outline of your original code demonstrates that the issue can be fixed by making `TDataPoint` covariant in the `IDataSeries` interface declaration:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ds = (IDataSeries<IDataPoint>)new DataSeries<SimpleDataPoint>();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IDataPoint { }

    public sealed class SimpleDataPoint : IDataPoint { }

    public interface IDataSeries<out TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint { }

    public class DataSeries<TDataPoint> : IDataSeries<TDataPoint> where TDataPoint : class, IDataPoint { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Reg Edit, however, if you read the body of the IDataSeries interface, you will see it cannot be covariant due to the Add(TDataPoint dataPoint) method. If you read the answer I posted above, you will see I extracted a "readonly" part of the dataseries and made that covariant. Thanks again!! Much appreciate all the help

Comment: @bboyle1234--I know. However, the question of the Add() method is a detail that came to light later (or you would of course have asked a specific question about that in the first place). 
The Add() conflict can be addressed in a variety of ways as an issue in its own right--as indeed you've now done, receiving some very creative input along the way. In the context of the original question though, and any lasting value it has on SO, I think it's still useful to show there's no fundamental problem with the arrangement of classes, interfaces and generic type parameters you first presented.